# How can I keep a Node script running on my server?

Tags: node.js, linux, server, server-side

I have a digital ocean server and I want to have a script run continuously. I am using node-scheduler inside this script so it runs a task every day (download images from the internet). The script doesn't stop until it is canceled, so that part works but how can I enable this to work inside my server?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're asking here.  If you have a script that works just fine on it's own, you can just wrap that into a function call, include the script in your server and then call the function you wrapped it in.

Comment: Consider using the scheduler built in to your operating system. From a terminal prompt, `man cron` to get started.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a process manager like [PM2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) or [Forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever).

Comment: Thanks for those! Are those options typical for my usage?

Comment: Very likely but your specific use case may be unique, hard to say :)